Преобразование данные во Vue 3
Мне необходимо прежде чем отобразить данные в дочернем компоненте их обработать. В какой части мне необходимо обработать данные: в methods, created или mounted? В данный момент обрабатываются в mounted, но мне кажетcя, что должно в created

получение данных и предварительную обработку лучше делать как можно раньше, поэтому created на мой взгляд подходит лучше

Зависит от того, какого типа обработка нужна. Если на основе входящих свойств необходимо создать собственные данные дочернего компонента, то логичнее всего это делать в функции data().
